# qsystemtrayicon opens many windows , need one

Tags: qt

When clicked multiple times, a qsystemtrayicon should open only once. How is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

That's up to you handle how many instances of a Window are fired up. QSystemTrayIcon has nothing to do with it. You most probably are creating a widget each time the system tray icon is clicked, instead of using just one and calling [QWidget::show()](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/qwidget.html#show) and [QWidget::hide()](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/qwidget.html#hide) respectively. That's the best shot i can take at your issue, given the thin description.